# How to Restart a Crashed Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to wait on a thread and restart it if it crashes.

It crashes on the part inside of the `if` statement. (If I take that out and replace it with a `Sleep` and then kill the thread inside Process Explorer I do not get any error (but also the thread does not restart). The error I get is an exception due to a stack overflow in `ws2_32.dll`. I tried calling the current function inside of the function to see if maybe it would work after having the `VirtualAlloc()`, `memcpy()` and what not done over again but I got the same error upon attempting to restart the thread.

I noticed though in Procexp that the new (restarted) thread actually ran for a little bit until the program crashed.

```
HANDLE theadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(code), NULL, 0, NULL);

while (true) {
    ...

    BOOL state = WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, 0); // Checks if the the thread has died and if so restarts it
    if (state == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    threadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(code), NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the thread restarts as if nothing ever happened.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The technical term for this kind of a crash is "undefined behavior". The execution thread is an indeterminate state, and it crashes. It is not possible to "restart" it in, some form or fashion, or return it to a known state, any more than you can survive a trip through a black hole, and return to the same universe you originally came from. Once the thread crashes, it's beyond the event horizon, and there is no turning back. Stick a fork in it. It's done.

Comment: Hunt and kill the bug whatever bug has you killing and recreating threads. It may be the most visible manifestation of many potential problems. Approach Undefined behaviour like you would a cancer. You don't know how far it reaches until you kill all of it..

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But surely I can detect if it has stopped running and if so just start a new one using the same machine code? (Machine code is hex encoded inside a char array)

Comment: Since all execution threads run in the same process space, I see nothing that will guarantee that the thread's corrupted execution state didn't corrupt the entire process. This kind of approach is only safe when applied to entire processes. An entire process crashed, you can start another one. It is the operating system's job to completely isolate the state of individual processes from each other. So, a crashed process can be properly terminated, and restarted. But you have no guarantees of stability, of any kind, for any attempt to restart after an execution thread crashed.

Comment: @user4581301 True, but I still want my process to act kind of like a "watchdog" process for my thread so if it dies a new one (with the same machine code) will be be executed.

Comment: A program cannot be trusted to watchdog itself for reasons Sam discussed above. Jeremy Friesner's answer offers an alternative: Multiple processes. Inter-communication is much more difficult (Keyterm : IPC), but all of the processes exist in their own protected space and you have to do something amazingly bad (and incredibly hard to do) to accidentally corrupt one process from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach won't work -- once the memory space of your process is corrupted (as it must be if a thread is crashing), trying to get useful behavior out of your program is a fool's errand.  Even if you think you've got it working, sooner or later you'll find out that it doesn't work reliably (e.g. it only crashes on certain hardware, or under certain conditions).

A better approach is to debug your code so that it never crashes in the first place -- that's the only way to make your program reliable and efficient.

If for some reason you can't do that, a (not very good) work-around would be to launch the buggy code inside a child process instead of in a thread -- that way, at least when the child process corrupts itself, your main process will be protected (and you can then safely start a new child process if you want to).  However, this is only a hack work-around; the proper fix is to make sure the crash doesn't happen in the first place, by making sure the code isn't buggy.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from this pointless endeavor. Answer accepted! :)

Comment: Hmm, I do have one remaining question though. If the memory space of the process becomes "corrupted" as soon as I kill the thread then why does the process not crash if I kill the thread without trying to restart it. (Replace the line of code inside the `if` statement with a `Sleep()` as I pointed out in my answer)

Comment: Imagine that your program is a person wandering around a large room in the dark.  In this analogy, the corruption is represented by a land-mine that has been placed at some particular location in the room.  Once planted, the land-mine is always there, but if your person/program decides to simply go to sleep rather than wandering around, he won't trigger it.  Even if he does wander around, he may just "get lucky" and never happen to go to the spot where he will step on the mine.  But if/when he *does* step on the mine, boom!  That's when the crash occurs.

Comment: Btw I do not think it is the act of killing the thread that causes the corruption (although unilaterally killing a thread introduces its own problems, in particular it prevents the thread from cleaning up any resources it may be holding at the moment of its death) -- rather the actions of the thread itself are likely the causes of the corruption.  In particular, a well-behaved thread should not ever need to be killed or restarted, as it will continue working as intended without help.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, I guess it's the attempt to reallocate or reuse that "booby-trapped" part of memory that does it. Thanks for the analogy, really makes trying to understand all this "undefined" madness easier!